# How to filter the radcombobox with unadjacent words?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

If i use the `radcombobox` :

as the following :

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddl_emp1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="false"
CollapseDelay="0" Culture="ar-EG" ExpandDelay="0" Filter="Contains"  ItemsPerRequest="100"
MarkFirstMatch="true" Skin="Outlook" Width="200px" EnableAutomaticLoadOnDemand="True"
EmptyMessage="-Type Employee Name -" ValidationGroup="2" ShowMoreResultsBox="True"                                           OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_emp1_SelectedIndexChanged">
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

if the items in the combo box consists of multi parts ,say for example :

```
Ran jack Rony
```

i wanna to get this item ,if i type  `Ran Rony` ,i get no result . i set the Filter property to "Contains"  instead "StartWith" but it doesn't fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are doing that search in SQL, and showing the result in ComboBox (could be RadCombobox).

You should do replace on space, in the sql query; and then do a like on that field.

Example:

You ask for: Ran jack Rony

Your SQL Query should do:

```
SET @filter = 'Ran jack Rony';
SET @filter = REPLACE(@filter, ' ', '%');
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE FieldName LIKE @filter;
```